# jQuery UI - issue with addClass/removeClass: Unwanted white background

Tags: jquery, jquery-ui, css, css-transitions

I'm trying to set an hover effect using jqueryUI's addClass() and removeClass().
This is what I came up with: http://jsfiddle.net/5aS77/ .
As you can see, 'onmouseout', the background becomes white for a time and then 'jumps' to blue again.
I just want the animation to go from blue to pink and vice verse without any 'interruptions'.

I know it is possible with CSS3, and I did try it already though it has 2 main cons:
1) Not all browsers support the transition property.
2) It doesn't have an onmouseout effect. (though it can be achieved with some JS.)

Comment: I agree that not all browsers support CSS3 transitions but you _can_ apply a (different) transition to entering and leaving an element, for example http://css-tricks.com/different-transitions-for-hover-on-hover-off/

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The *white flash* is because jQuery doesn't have a base colour to animate from as the background-color is set on the `.nav` class and not the `<a>` elements.

You can edit the rules as follows to remove the white flash.

```
.nav a {
    background-color:blue;
    ...
}

.nav .a_hover { // <--- need the .nav here otherwise CSS specificity results in blue still winning
    ...
}
```

Also, if you want, here is a slightly cleaner implementation of the jQuery:

```
$('a').on({
    mouseenter:function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'#f89ed5'}, 250);
    },
    mouseleave:function() {
        $(this).stop().animate({backgroundColor:'blue'}, 250);
    }
});
```

With this, the `.a_hover` class can be removed, although you still need the `background-color:blue` on the `.nav a` rule to avoid the initial white flash. The other properties in the `.a_hover` are not needed since they already exit on the `.nav a` rule.

Answer (score 3):

**DEMO:**    [Jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/5aS77/2/)

```
 var links = document.getElementsByTagName("a");
    for(var i = 0; i < links.length; i++) {
        links[i].onmouseover = hoverHandler;
        links[i].onmouseout = outHandler;
    }

    function hoverHandler() {
        $(this).addClass("a_hover",250);
    }

    function outHandler() {
        $(this).removeClass("a_hover");
    }​
```

Comment: Thanks, although it doesn't solve the problem.
There is still a white background showing for a moment in addClass(), plus, I'm looking for the removeClass effect so it doesn't do the job well. Still thanks for trying!

Comment: what is you browser, I dont see a white space

Comment: Removing the time interval from removeClass works for me using Opera and Firefox

Comment: I am also using chrome `19.0.1084.52 m`

Answer (score 1):

If you look in the jquery docs you will see there is a hover event - if you are going to use jquery it's worth making the most of it. (http://api.jquery.com/hover/).

Saying that you could achieve the same thing without js:

```
.nav a {
    display:block;
    float:left;
    text-decoration:none;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;
    height:31px;
    width:auto;
    color: #000;
    padding: 11px 20px 0 20px;
    overflow:hidden;
}
.nav a:hover{
    display:block;
    overflow:hidden;
    background-color:#f89ed5;
    text-shadow:1px 1px #FFF;
    padding: 11px 20px 0 20px;
}​
```

answering the question:

remove the numbers e.g.

```
function hoverHandler() {
                $(this).addClass("a_hover");
            }

            function outHandler() {
                $(this).removeClass("a_hover");
            }​
```

http://api.jquery.com/addClass/

Comment: I know it can be achieved with js. Although I want that fade in/out kind of animation...